# Flashing blue "error" - is this part of the game, or a fault?

Tags: technical-issues, portal-2

This is what I get when I start Portal 2, after the introduction "Look Up" "Look Down" screen.

Is this part of the game, or is there something wrong with my installation?

[image: Error]

Comment: Back in the Half-Life days, this was Red. Seems they changed it to fit the Portal style... :)

Comment: It was red in the first Portal.

Comment: Lovely. It recalls the work of Wayne White. http://www.esquire.com/features/esquire-100/waynewhite1007

Comment: Reminds me of joining Garry's Mod servers when you don't have mods installed.

Comment: @Sadly Or without CS:S installed.  :P

Comment: If you use noclip in the first chamber you can see it. THought that might help

Comment: @Harris There are a couple maps with disembodied error messages floating out of bounds.  In those cases, it may just be a lack of cleaning-up and their references are to models that may not exist at all.

Comment: @Harris I don't think seeing the full word "Error" is helpful.  Or seeing the error somewhere else, if that's what you mean.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

This means an error in the Steam download.

Verify the game integrity (Right-click Portal 2, Properties, Local Files, Verify integrity of game cache) and it should re-download the corrupt files.

Comment: In-game error messages? Awesome!

Comment: Not strictly. It's what's shown when a model can't be found. They'd need something to replace it.

Comment: Gotta love the source engine for that